# Removing characters from List of Strings

Tags: string, scala

To remove characters from a List of Strings I use :

```
val validLines : List[String] = List("test[" , "test]")

    val charsToClean: List[String] = List("\"", "[", "]", "'")

    val filtered = validLines.map(line => line.replace(charsToClean(0), "")
      .replace(charsToClean(1), "")
      .replace(charsToClean(2), "")
      .replace(charsToClean(3), ""))
```

I'm attempting use a inner map function instead of hard coding the positions of the chars to replace :

```
val filtered1 : List[String] = validLines.map(line => charsToClean.map {c => line.replace(c , "")  })
```

But receive compiler error :

```
mismatch; found : List[List[String]] required: List[String]
```

Should result of `line.replace(c , "")` not be returned ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because your code is more like: for every string and for every unwanted char, return replacement **for this very symbol** (n^2 strings).

What you probably wanted to do can be achieved using the following snippet:

```
val rawLines : List[String] = List("test[" , "test]")
val blacklist: Set[Char] = Set('\"', '[', ']' ,''')
rawLines.map(line => line.filterNot(c => blacklist.contains(c)))
// res2: List[String] = List(test, test)
```

Or alternatively, using regexp, as @ka4eli has shown in his answer.

Comment: thanks, if I use a List[String] instead of Set[Char] to contain the blacklist items the items are not filtered ?

Comment: @blue-sky, you can use `List[Char]`, but not `List[String]`

Comment: @ka4eli why? contains method should behave same, be it List of Strings or Set of chars ?

Comment: when you filter on `String`, the current iteratee is of type `Char`.

Answer (score 4):

`replaceAll` can contain more complex regex constructed with `|` (or) operator:

```
validLines.map(_.replaceAll("\\[|\\]|'|\"", ""))
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `foldLeft` instead of `map`.

```
val validLines : List[String] = List("test[" , "test]")

val charsToClean: List[String] = List("\"", "[", "]", "'")

val filtered : List[String] = validLines.map(line => charsToClean.foldLeft(line)(_.replace(_, "")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Equivalent to @om-nom-nom though using a for comprehension syntax; given a set of characters to erase,

```
val charsToClean = """"[]'""".toSet
```

then

```
for (l <- validLines) yield l.filterNot(charsToClean)
```

where implicit set inclusion `Char => Boolean` function is applied in `filterNot`.